# Save HTML content of some specific tags using HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I have a question of how can I use HTMLAgilityPack for extracting HTML content of some specific tag.
I provide the following HTML code:

```
<td class="text_11" width="80%" valign="top">
     <span class="text_11">Producer:</span>
     <a class="link_11b" href="/Asus_producer.htm">Asus</a>
     <br>
     <p>
        <table class="text_11" border="0" style="width: 100%;">
          <tbody>
        </table>
     <p> </p>
</td>
```

What actually I need to do is to extract the HTML code (as it appears here) that is contained by `<td class="text_11" width="80%" valign="top">`, even there are more and more tags inside of this `<td>`.

What I need is to save into a string this text (which is HTML) : 
`

```
 <span class="text_11">Producer:</span>
         <a class="link_11b" href="/Asus_producer.htm">Asus</a>
         <br>
         <p>
            <table class="text_11" border="0" style="width: 100%;">
              <tbody>
            </table>
         <p> </p>
```

`
Thanks.

Comment: Side note - you have issues in your html - there is not closed `tbody` and `br` elements, last `p` element is closed but not opened, also table is nested in paragraph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var xpath = "//td[@class='text_11' and @width='80%' and @valign='top']";
var td = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(xpath);
string html = td.InnerHtml; // check also if td is not null
```